# Spring Boot application form validation is intercepted by /error page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Currently I am working on a project which used Spring Boot 1.2.7, and freemarker as page template engine.

I am trying to use Bean Validation as before, but it does not work as expected.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String signup(@Valid @ModelAttribute("signup") SignupForm signup, BindingResult result) {
    log.debug("signup form @" + signup);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "/signup";
    }

    //AccountDetails details = accountService.register(form);
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

When the bean validation is failed, it redirected to Spring Boot built-in */error* page instead of displaying error messages in the **signup** page.

Comment: Can you give more code of SignupForm and modelattribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue in `SignupForm` object and `signup` model attribute. Spring can not map both.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to redirect to signup page like **:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String signup(@Valid @ModelAttribute("signup") SignupForm signup, BindingResult result) {
    log.debug("signup form @" + signup);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "signup";
    }
    //AccountDetails details = accountService.register(form);
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```